# Override just a few cases of data in Eq instance implementation

Tags: haskell

I have a data type

```
data MyType = Any | A | B | C ...
```

and the semantics of "Any" is that it should be equivalent to all other cases. I thought that the most elegant way is to implement my own Eq instance, starting with

```
instance Eq MyType where
    Any == _ = True
    _ == Any = True
```

But now I don't see a way of avoiding repetitive and silly code like

```
    A == A = True
    B == B = True
    ...
```

I though of "abusing" the show function and just do `x == y = (show x) == (show y)` but is there a cleaner way?

Comment: I think adding an abstract type that acts like a wildcard is probably better. Then you can make it an instance of a `Monoid`, etc. as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could perhaps do something like this:

```
data Wildcard a = Any | Card a

data NewType = A | B | C | ... deriving Eq

type OldType = Wildcard NewType

instance (Eq a) => Eq (Wildcard a) where
  Any    == _      = True
  _      == Any    = True
  Card l == Card r = l == r
```

This way, the compiler auto-derives `Eq OldType` for you, and we have `Eq NewType` with the expected semantics. (And we can apply `Any` over any type we fancy...)

Answer (score 11):

You've gotten some good answers explaining how to do this. Now I'm going to explain why you absolutely should not do this.

A class in hand Haskell is not just a bunch of methods. It also comes with laws. These laws are essential for allowing people to write class-polymorphic functions that make sense. Unfortunately, the `Prelude` does not document any laws for the `Eq` class. The reason is that people wanted the convenience of using `==` and `/=` for floating point representations, whose usual notions of "equality" are ill-behaved. I believe this was a grave mistake on the part of the Haskell Committee.

So what laws should `Eq` instances obey? One obvious one relates its methods:

```
a /= b = not (a == b)
```

Other important, commonly accepted laws are the ones necessary to make `==` describe an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation). In particular, for all `a`, `b`, and `c`,

1. Reflexive law: `a == a = True` (see footnote)
2. Symmetric law: `a == b = b == a`
3. Transitive law: If `a == b && b == c = True`, then `a == c = True`

There's also a general assumption of (approximate) substitutivity. If `f` is a typical function (not a weird abstraction-breaking internal or debugging one), and `a == b = True`, then `f a == f b = True`. In combination with the other laws, this means that `==` reflects mathematical equality of an underlying *model* that the type represents.

Your definition of `==` violates transitivity. In particular,

```
A == Any && Any == B = True
```

but

```
A == B = False
```

This means that if you use your type with any function polymorphic over `Eq` instances, you will have to read the source code of that function to determine whether it will behave the way you want. If the implementation of that function changes, you'll have to read its source code again to check that it will still do what you want. In practice, this is pretty awful.

How can you fix the problem? Instead of writing a weird `Eq` instance, write your own function for comparing cards!

```
data Wildcard a = Any | Card a

data NonWild = A | B | C | ... deriving Eq

matching :: Eq a => Wildcard a -> Wildcard a -> Bool
matching (Card a) (Card b) = a == b
matching _ _ = True
```

#### Footnote

Values in Haskell may be infinite or incompletely defined. As a result, the reflexive law may not be strictly true. For example, `repeat 1 == repeat 1` will never terminate (it denotes a "bottom" value). So in practice, the appropriate reflexive law states that `a == a` is not `False`. It's generally expected that `==` will terminate when its arguments are finite and well-defined.

Comment: This is the right answer. Violating transitivity is a bad idea.

Comment: Unfortunately, some APIs don’t provide a higher-order function taking a predicate, and only allow you to use `Eq` (`Ord`, &c.). For that purpose I typically make a `newtype` wrapper with the appropriate instance, and at least document if it’s not law-abiding.

Comment: @JonPurdy, when an instance requires runtime context, you can use `reflection`. But a flagrantly bogus instance will at least make your code very hard to work with.

Answer (score 6):

You can also abuse other classes, like `Enum`:

```
data MyType = Any | A | B | C ...
  deriving Enum

instance Eq MyType where
  Any == _ = True
  _ == Any = True
  a == b = fromEnum a == fromEnum b
```

But what the 'best' approach for this is ultimately depends on your actual use case. If you just have a handful of cases I'd recommend just writing them out by hand; There's a case to be made for avoiding repetitive code but don't go overboard with this to the point where you refuse to write code altogether.

Answer (score 3):

You could derive Enum and use it to define the Eq class

```
data T = Any | A | B | C deriving (Enum, Show)

instance Eq T where
  a == b = fromEnum a == fromEnum b || fromEnum a == 0 || fromEnum b == 0
```

Comment: Derived `Eq` instances actually do something very similar to this, with the `dataToTag#` primop that's also used for derived `Enum` instances.